# Incrementally "scroll" container left/right on click with pure css

Tags: css

I am trying to create a pure CSS solution that will scroll a set of elements incrementally right or left some fixed value on click of a href link. I have the basics working in that I can scroll right or left on click of the corresponding button however subsequent clicks only toggle between the initial positions. I cannot increment multiple times to the left or right.

Remember, goal is pure CSS please as I am trying to either render a working POC or to show that javascript will be required as this can't be done with pure css.

http://plnkr.co/edit/itGDeyE8sfXtEbhBlycJ?p=preview

**HTML**

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <a id="left" href="#left">&lt;</a>
    <a id="right" href="#right">&gt;</a>

    <div class="f-slideshow">
      <div class="items">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>
        <span>5</span>
        <span>6</span>
        <span>7</span>
        <span>8</span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.f-slideshow{
  position:relative;
  max-width:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}

.f-slideshow .items{
  display:inline-table;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
  background:#999;
  position:relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.f-slideshow span{
  margin:3px;
  padding:5px;
  background:#ddd;
  border-radius:3px;
}

#right {
  position: relative;
  left: 125px;
}

#right:target ~ .f-slideshow .items{
  transform: translateX( -50px );
}

#left:target ~ .f-slideshow .items{
  transform: translateX( 0px );
}
```

Comment: Can you add additional HTML?

Comment: Yes but as long as the right or left scroll is still the domain of only two elements (I cant have N number of anchor tags to target N number of items)

Comment: Something like this? http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-anything-slider-with-just-css--cms-24278

Comment: That example does not incrementally scroll the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new anchors for each scrolled position:

**HTML**

```
<a class="pos" id="pos1"></a>
<a class="pos" id="pos2"></a>
<a class="pos" id="pos3"></a>
<a class="pos" id="pos4"></a>
```

**CSS**

```
#pos1:target ~ .f-slideshow .items {transform: translateX(    0px );}
#pos2:target ~ .f-slideshow .items {transform: translateX(  -50px );}
#pos3:target ~ .f-slideshow .items {transform: translateX( -100px );}
#pos4:target ~ .f-slideshow .items {transform: translateX( -150px );}
```

---

Use multiple anchors for the left and right buttons, but set their position to absolute so only one appears at a time.

Point them to each "position" anchor.

Use `z-index: 1;` for the first left and first right buttons:

**HTML**

```
<a class="left"  id="left1"  href="#pos1">&lt;</a>
<a class="left"  id="left2"  href="#pos2">&lt;</a>
<a class="left"  id="left3"  href="#pos3">&lt;</a>
<a class="right" id="right1" href="#pos2">&gt;</a>
<a class="right" id="right2" href="#pos3">&gt;</a>
<a class="right" id="right3" href="#pos4">&gt;</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.left, .right {
  position: absolute;
}

.right {
  left: 135px;
}

#left1, #right1 {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

---

Change the `z-index`of the appropriate left or right button, depending on scrolled position:

**CSS**

```
#pos1:target ~ #left1,  #pos1:target ~ #right1,
#pos2:target ~ #left1,  #pos2:target ~ #right2, 
#pos3:target ~ #left2,  #pos3:target ~ #right3, 
#pos4:target ~ #left3,  #pos4:target ~ #right3 {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

---

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/CaKp8JNE6ThxywEArlwg?p=preview)

Comment: That looks beautiful! Very nice it leverages mutliple anchors without exposing that there are multiple anchors to the user. That is perfectly acceptable.